# What were the potential consequences of Israel's strike on the Osirak reactor?

Tags: israel

Was there any plutonium at the plant at the time?

Comment: "moral" is not a term that is defined in a way that is useful for historical study and research.  The term is useful for ethics, philosophy and pub conversations, but from a historical perspective, it is subjective. The question is likely to be closed on this basis.  RE: plutonium, what research have you done?  Please review [help] to better understand the culture and assumptions of this site and revise the question to fit within that culture.

Comment: You may wish to include some links to prior research - links to the Osirak reactor strike, to Israel's statements on the events, etc.  Questions that show prior research generally get much better reactions and answers.

Comment: This question is so terse as to leave wide open the actual question, and whether or not you are viewing that strike in isolation, or within the context of the geopolitical factors that led to the strike, and the geo political fallout from the strike.  The title question has zero amplification in the text of the question. That's not how to do it.  I recommend this be closed as incomplete and unclear, unless the title question and context is presented so that its scope fits our site's standards.

Comment: I think this is unclear - 'potential consequences'? Also, the OP has not visited the site since Feb 8 so we are unlikely to get any clarification. I'll retract my vote if the OP improves the question.

Comment: The body of your question does not match the title, could you clarify it?

Comment: there was actually according to “Israel's Wars &amp; Operations.” Operation Opera - Raid on Iraqi Nuclear Reactor, www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/operation-opera-raid-on-iraqi-nuclear-reactor.
there was 25 pounds of enriched uranium

Answer (score 1):

> **Original Question:** Was the Israeli Attack on the Osirak reactor Moral?
>
> Was there any plutonium at the plant at the time?

Morality is subjective.  Certainly from an Israeli perspective it was moral.  Iraq was one of Israel's greatest existential threats in 1980.   Any action to dissuade an agressive existential threat, who's demonstrated a proclivity for using military action first; from obtaining nuclear weapons can be broadly referred to as moral.  As I remember at the time the American President Ronald Reagan criticized Israel for taking this action.  His Vice President George Bush as I remember, on the eve of the first gulf war didn't share Reagan's feelings in 1990.

As for the nuclear site containing Plutonium.  No it was a Uranium reactor, which would produce Plutonium only after operational.  It's been said the Plutonium the plant was capable of producing was limited.  Either way the Osirak reactor was not operational.  It was feared that the Plant contained Uranium at the time of the attack.  That was a fear of the Iranian government who was consulted by Israel prior to the attack(*).   That's why Israel did not strike the dome itself but the control room and the reactor's cooling system.

> [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Opera)
>   In a 2003 speech, Richard Wilson, a professor of physics at Harvard University who visually inspected the partially damaged reactor in December 1982, said that "to collect enough plutonium [for a nuclear weapon] using Osirak would've taken decades, not years".[36] In 2005, Wilson further commented in

(*) Israel representatives met with representatives of Iran in Paris a month before the attack and negotiated emergency landing rights for Israeli pilots involved in the attack if necessary.  Iran had tried to hit the site itself prior to Israel but were unsuccessful.  This was the first of ongoing discussions leading up to the attack.

**source:**
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Opera)

Comment: Please revise this answer now that the "was it moral" red herring has been edited out.

Comment: You think I should revise it or write a new answer?  The new question is entirely different.

Comment: I'd revise it, since the revised question needs a revised answer.  There will be some crossover in material, I think.